# Porque sale null? Herencia java

Tags: java, poo

```
public class PracticaHerenciaSimple {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("** CLASE PADRE VEHICULO **");

        Vehiculo vehiculo = new Vehiculo() {};// constructor por defecto creado por el compilador
        vehiculo.marca="MARCA X";
        vehiculo.modelo=2012;
        vehiculo.nombre="NOMBRE X";
       Aereo aereo= new Aereo();
       aereo.nombreAereo="NOMBRE AEREO X";
       Acuatico acuatico= new Acuatico();
       acuatico.nombreAcuatico="NOMBRE ACUATICO X";
       Avion avion= new Avion();
       avion.aerolinea="X";
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.printf("\nEn la CLASE PADRE VEHICULO se tiene "
                + "marca: %s, nombre: %s, modelo: %d", vehiculo.marca, vehiculo.nombre, vehiculo.modelo);
       vehiculo.transporte();
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("** SUBCLASE AEREO **");
        System.out.printf("En la clase hija AEREO se tiene marca: "
                + "%s, nombre: %s, modelo: %d, "
                + "nombre Aereo: %s\n",aereo.marca, aereo.nombre, aereo.modelo, aereo.nombreAereo);
        aereo.transporte();
    }

}
```

---

```
public abstract class Vehiculo {

    protected int modelo;
    protected String nombre;
    protected String marca;

    public void transporte() {
        System.out.println("\nMetodo transporte() de la clase VEHICULO");

    }
    }
```

---

No funciona la herencia, sale null.

Comment: ¿Al hacer qué cosa dices que sale null? Las clases abstractas no se instancian... Si vehiculo es abstracta como dice tu ejemplo, no puedes hacer "new Vehiculo" en tu código. El método main que publicaste, ¿Compila?

Comment: ¿Cuál es la herencia? ¿De quién hereda? ¿Dónde sale `NULL`? ¿Cuál es el mensaje de error?

Comment: Al ejecutar el programa, me sale null aqui, System.out.printf("En la clase hija AEREO se tiene marca: "
                + "%s, nombre: %s, modelo: %d, "
                + "nombre Aereo: %s\n",aereo.marca, aereo.nombre, aereo.modelo, aereo.nombreAereo);
        aereo.transporte();. Estoy heredando de la clase vehiculo.

Comment: El programa compila

Comment: no imprime el modelo, marca y nombre, lo que necesito que imprima. Sale null

Comment: Sale null porque nunca seteaste ninguno de esos valores para el objeto "aereo".

Comment: Okay, me estare fijando mas en el codigo. Es todo lo que necesito.Resuelto.

Comment: Dale, y cualquier cosa pregunta de nuevo, quizás algo mas concreto. Por ultimo, no estas usando del todo bien la herencia. Vehiculo avion = new Avion("marcax", 2012, "nombrex"), quizás eso tenga algo mas de sentido. Pero todo depende del problema que estas tratando de resolver.

Comment: Claro eso era @AlejandroGiorgi. Pues los miembros están declarados como `protected`.

Comment: Si, están declarados como protected pero tanto el objeto "vehiculo" como el objeto "aereo" son instancias diferentes, objetos diferentes, por lo tanto asignarle valor a uno de ellos no implica que ese mismo valor se asigne en el otro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como es una clase abstracta, debe tener un método abstracto y la clase que la va a usar, debe extender de la clase abstracta

```
public class mombreClase extends claseAbstracta
```